# Oracle - How to view initialization parameter settings?

Tags: sql, oracle, parameters, dblink

I am looking to identify the value of an initialization parameter ([GLOBAL_NAMES](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams088.htm)) in an `Oracle` database. I'm assuming it is available in one of the many DBA_ views but I haven't been able to find it.

Does anyone know an easy way to identify these initialization settings on the Database as a non-administrator? I am using Toad 12.6 and do have `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE`.

**What I've Tried**

- I've searched online and see many references to altering these but not of simply viewing the current setting
- Looked up a few promising DBA_ views (ones with "parameter" in the title)
- Searched on SO - had a few promising leads but the hyperlinks are dead
- Tried searching through the [Oracle DBA Admin handbook](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/toc.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select value from v$parameter where name = 'global_names';
```

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_2085.htm for more information on that view.

Answer (score 1):

In case you lack `SELECT` privileges on view `V$PARAMETER`, you can use also package [DBMS_UTILITY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_util.htm#ARPLS73249) to get the values:

```
DECLARE
    intval INTEGER;
    strval VARCHAR2(4000);
    res NUMBER;
BEGIN
    res := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_PARAMETER_VALUE ('global_names', intval, strval);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'intval = ' || intval );     
END;
```

Comment: +1 This is good info as well, thank you. Just FYI, though, for my database I had to run Set ServerOutput On; before your script in order to see the value.